# Solve Frenet Serret code with out gaps or twists

Tags: c#, path, geometry, bezier

Working on 3d tube extrusion along a Bezier path in 3d space using C# and have come to an impasse. I have integrated GLMSharp for vectors, dot, cross and normal etc.. I'm unsure how to create an Up Vector and whether that's the problem.  I am outputting to .3ds format and the following image shows gaps or twists in some cases.  I am inquiring for a solution.

```
//  frenet serret code
void get_circle(int i, double theta, float[,] mmp, float[] p1, float[] p2, float rad,float[] cen)
{
    float[] n = new float[3];

    vec3 tp1 = new vec3(p1[0], p1[1], p1[2]);
    vec3 tp2 = new vec3(p2[0], p2[1], p2[2]);

    vec3 T = (tp2 - tp1);
    T = T.Normalized;

    vec3 B = vec3.Cross(T, tp2 + tp1);
    B = B.Normalized;

    vec3 N = vec3.Cross(B, T);

    N = N.Normalized;

    float x = (float)Math.Cos(theta)*rad;
    float y = (float)Math.Sin(theta)*rad;

    vec3 vertex = tp1 + B * x + N * y;

    mmp[i,0] = cen[0] + vertex.x;
    mmp[i,1] = cen[1] + vertex.y;
    mmp[i,2] = cen[2] + vertex.z;
}
```

[twists or gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vfZz.gif)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, `p1` and `p2` are points, so `tp2 + tp1` defines some point (vector)  that has no relevance to binormal `B`. When this vector is collinear with tangent `T`, you have got zero `B` adn gap.

To calculate Frenel trihedron in some point of path, you need at least three consequtive points of that path  - let's name them `Prev, Curr, Next`.

Binormal `B` might be calculated as *(except for case of three collinear points - here binormal is not defined, and one might use previous value if possible)*

```
 B = Cross(Next-Curr, Curr - Prev)
```

Note that more reliable value of tangent also might account for neighbor points  - so instead of

```
T = Next - Curr
```

you can use (when spacing is rather uniform)  ([compare here](https://www.shodor.org/refdesk/Resources/Algorithms/NumericalDifferentiation/))

```
T = Next - Prev
```

Answer (score 0):

MBo, Thanx for the expedited response and the routine based on your advise is as follows:

```
void cap_middle(int i, double theta, float[,] mmp, vec3 prev, vec3 curr, vec3 next,float rad,float[] cen)
    {
        vec3 T = (curr - next);

        T = T.Normalized;

        vec3 B = vec3.Cross(next - curr, curr - prev);

        B = B.Normalized;


        vec3 N = vec3.Cross(B, T);

        N = N.Normalized;

        float x = (float)Math.Cos(theta)*rad;
        float y = (float)Math.Sin(theta)*rad;

        vec3 vertex = curr + B * x + N * y;

        mmp[i,0] = cen[0] + vertex.x;
        mmp[i,1] = cen[1] + vertex.y;
        mmp[i,2] = cen[2] + vertex.z;
    }
```

Although, another problem cropped up, the connecting cylinders from each Bezier path connected seems to have a winding order problem as shown in included graphic.  The vertices are not consistent. Any Ideas?

[winding order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NeG8.gif)

Comment: Seems `T` direction is backward. Forward one is `(next-curr)` or `(next - prev)`. This correction also causes change of `N` sign - perhaps mmp order will be right.